# How get basepath from model or helper en Zend Framework 3

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-framework3

I recently decided to use Zend Framework 3 after 3 years of using Zend Framework 1. This decision has given me headaches, Zend 3 instead of making things easier made things more difficult.

In Zend 1, I customize the url for the selected template in the database as follows:

```
public function getUrl(string $file = '')
{
    if($this->_helperBaseUrl === null) {
        $this->_helperBaseUrl = new Zend_View_Helper_BaseUrl();
    }
    return $this->_helperBaseUrl->baseUrl($file);
}

public function getSkinUrl(string $file = '')
{
    $themePath = 'themes/my-theme/'; //get from database
    return $this->getUrl($themePath . ltrim($file, '/\\'));
}
```

Then in any part of the application (models, helpers, plugins and views) I can access this function like this:

```
//view/scripts/index/index.phtml
$url_logo = My::app()->getSkinUrl('logo.jpg');
//this return http://example.com/themes/my-theme/logo.jpg
```

In Zend 3 it has been very difficult for me. Does anyone know of any way to do it in Zend 3? Or How to get the baseUrl from a model in Zend 3?

Comment: You just late to the party 5 years :)

Comment: @tasmaniski 3 years ago I was using ZF2, but it was slower than ZF1. For that reason, I have continued using ZF1 :)

Answer (score 2):

In Zend Framework 2/3 you can inject almost any class into another. For example if you need `basePath` plugin (which is available in view context) you can inject this plugin into your model/service or controller class. This is the recommended way:

This is class where you need this plugin or any other service

```
use Zend\View\Helper\BasePath;

class MyService
{
    /**
     * @var BasePath
     */
    protected $plugin;

    /**
     * MyService constructor.
     *
     * @param BasePath $basePath
     */
    public function __construct(BasePath $basePath)
    {
        $this->plugin = $basePath;
    }

    /**
     * @return BasePath
     */
    public function getPlugin()
    {
        return $this->plugin;
    }

    /**
     * @param BasePath $plugin
     */
    public function setPlugin($plugin)
    {
        $this->plugin = $plugin;
    }
}
```

Now, you need to factory to inject one dependency into another

```
use Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;
use MyNamespace\Service\MyService;

class MyServiceFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    /**
     *
     * @param ContainerInterface $container
     * @param string $requestedName
     * @param null|array $options
     * @return MyService
     */
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
    {
        $class = $requestedName ? $requestedName : MyService::class;
        $plugin = $container->get('ViewHelperManager')->get('BasePath'); // inject this class
        $myService = new $class($plugin); // into this class

        return $myService;

    }
    /**
     * Provided for backwards compatibility; proxies to __invoke().
     *
     * @param ContainerInterface|ServiceLocatorInterface $container
     * @return MyService
     */
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $container)
    {
        return $this($container, MyService::class);
    }
}
```

Ok, now `MyService` has `basePath` plugin, but to use it in controller you have to inject your service into controller. So...

IndexController

```
use MyNamespace\Service\MyService;
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;

class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{
    /**
     * @var MyService
     */
    protected $service;

    /**
     * IndexController constructor.
     * 
     * @param MyService $service
     */
    public function __construct(MyService $service)
    {
        $this->service = $service;
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $plugin = $this->service->getPlugin(); // Zend\View\Helper\BasePath object
        //...
    }
}
```

... and factory for our controller...

```
use Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;
use MyNamespace\Controller\IndexController;

class IndexControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    /**
     *
     * @param ContainerInterface $container
     * @param string $requestedName
     * @param null|array $options
     * @return IndexController
     */
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
    {
        $class = $requestedName ? $requestedName : IndexController::class;
        $myService = $container->getServiceLocator()->get('MyNamespace\Service\MyService');
        $controller = new $class($myService);

        return $controller;

    }
    /**
     * Provided for backwards compatibility; proxies to __invoke().
     *
     * @param ContainerInterface|ServiceLocatorInterface $container
     * @return IndexController
     */
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $container)
    {
        return $this($container, IndexController::class);
    }
}
```

It's almost done. Last step is to set configuration in `module.config.php` file

```
use MyNamespace\Controller;
use MyNamespace\Factory;

return [
    //...
    'service_manager' => [
        'factories' => [
            Service\MyService::class => Factory\Service\MyServiceFactory::class
        ]
    ],
    'controllers' => [
        'factories' => [
            Controller\IndexController::class => Factory\Controller\IndexControllerFactory::class
        ],
    ],
]
```

Easy, isn't it?
If you need plugin in controller, but not in your model/service class, you can skip `MyService` part of this "tutorial" and inject plugin directly into controller class