# Just Created a form with ZF2 and its giving the error

Tags: forms, input, zend-framework2

I have got the following error when i have access my new created form:

```
Zend\Form\Factory::create expects the $spec["type"] to implement one of Zend\Form\ElementInterface, Zend\Form\FieldsetInterface, or Zend\Form\FormInterface; received Hidden
```

Here is the my AlbumForm.php file :

```
 namespace Album\Form;

 use Zend\Form\Form;

 class AlbumForm extends Form
     {
 public function __construct($name = null)
 {
     // we want to ignore the name passed
     parent::__construct('album');

     $this->add(array(
         'name' => 'id',
         'type' => 'Hidden',
     ));
     $this->add(array(
         'name' => 'title',
         'type' => 'Text',
         'options' => array(
             'label' => 'Title',
         ),
     ));
     $this->add(array(
         'name' => 'artist',
         'type' => 'Text',
         'options' => array(
             'label' => 'Artist',
         ),
     ));
     $this->add(array(
         'name' => 'submit',
         'type' => 'Submit',
         'attributes' => array(
             'value' => 'Go',
             'id' => 'submitbutton',
         ),
     ));
 }
}
```

**And here is the model Album.php code for the form:**

```
// Add content to these methods:
 public function setInputFilter(InputFilterInterface $inputFilter)
 {
     throw new \Exception("Not used");
 }

 public function getInputFilter()
 {
     if (!$this->inputFilter) {
         $inputFilter = new InputFilter();

         $inputFilter->add(array(
             'name'     => 'id',
             'required' => true,
             'filters'  => array(
                 array('name' => 'Int'),
             ),
         ));

         $inputFilter->add(array(
             'name'     => 'artist',
             'required' => true,
             'filters'  => array(
                 array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                 array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
             ),
             'validators' => array(
                 array(
                     'name'    => 'StringLength',
                     'options' => array(
                         'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                         'min'      => 1,
                         'max'      => 100,
                     ),
                 ),
             ),
         ));

         $inputFilter->add(array(
             'name'     => 'title',
             'required' => true,
             'filters'  => array(
                 array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                 array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
             ),
             'validators' => array(
                 array(
                     'name'    => 'StringLength',
                     'options' => array(
                         'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                         'min'      => 1,
                         'max'      => 100,
                     ),
                 ),
             ),
         ));

         $this->inputFilter = $inputFilter;
     }

     return $this->inputFilter;
 }
```

Here is the Stack Trace:

```
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\zendtest\vendor\ZF2\library\Zend\Form\Form.php(143): Zend\Form\Factory->create(Array)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\zendtest\module\Album\src\Album\Form\AlbumForm.php(22): Zend\Form\Form->add(Array)
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\zendtest\module\Album\src\Album\Controller\AlbumController.php(41): Album\Form\AlbumForm->__construct()
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\zendtest\vendor\ZF2\library\Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController.php(87): Album\Controller\AlbumController->addAction()
#4 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\zendtest\vendor\ZF2\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(468): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\zendtest\vendor\ZF2\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(208): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\zendtest\vendor\ZF2\library\Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController.php(108): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\zendtest\vendor\ZF2\library\Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener.php(113): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response))
#9 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\zendtest\vendor\ZF2\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(468): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#11 C:\xampp\htdocs\zendtest\vendor\ZF2\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(208): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#12 C:\xampp\htdocs\zendtest\vendor\ZF2\library\Zend\Mvc\Application.php(297): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#13 C:\xampp\htdocs\zendtest\public\index.php(14): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()
#14 {main}
```

How I can resolve the above mentioned error and made the module work fine.
let me know if any further code is needed to be explore the issue.

Comment: Are you sure this error comes from AlbumForm? Check in your stack trace. Did you check if form works without hidden input?

Comment: Yes i have checked by changing removing the hidden field but still the same error. please check the updated question with stack trace errors:

Comment: What version of Zend do you use? It looks like older version. If you have installed it via composer, do `$ composer update`

Comment: That's fixed by now its start showing this error:
Deprecated: You are retrieving the service locator from within the class StickyNotes\Controller\StickyNotesController. Please be aware that ServiceLocatorAwareInterface is deprecated and will be removed in version 3.0, along with the ServiceLocatorAwareInitializer. You will need to update your class to accept all dependencies at creation, either via constructor arguments or setters, and use a factory to perform the injections. in C:\xampp\htdocs\zendtest\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Controller\AbstractController.php on line 258 @SzymonM

Comment: Using `getServiceLocator()` in controller is not recommended and in future this method will be removed. The recommended way is to inject dependency through factory.  I showed in your previouse question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42643523/zend-servicemanager-servicemanagerget-was-unable-to-fetch-or-create-an-instanc/42716355#42716355) how to use factory or follow steps from this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42548822/how-get-basepath-from-model-or-helper-en-zend-framework-3/42552602#42552602. It's about controller plugin but same way you can inject any class you want.

Comment: So for every module we have to create a separate factory ? @SzymonM

Comment: Not really. Factories are used for classes which need dependency of "global" (usually single instance) object. Class `A` needs (depends on) class `B`, so you have to inject class `B` into `A` to use it. Good example is db connection. You don't want to (probably) have multiple connections to same database, so you have to share same db instance among your classes. So, sometimes your module will not need any factory and sometimes it will require few/several.  
Keep in mind that Zend has predefined factories you can use.

Comment: can you please add answer to this question so i will accept and will helpful for the others? @SzymonM

Comment: Sure, give me few minutes. Thanks! :)

Comment: Why this line is always red in my IDE. its showing error what is wrong in this ?
$class = $requestedName ? $requestedName : AlbumController::class; @SzymonM

Comment: Does it show you any info? Maybe your IDE does not recognize `ClassName::class` syntax. It was introduced in PHP 5.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We fixed issue in comments, but I post answer so if someone has similar problem it may be helpful.

First of all. Check if your Zend library is up to date.
If so, then try to check if problem is only with one certain input (comment/remove temporary) or it is global problem. Maybe you just did typo in type of input (Zend would probably throw exception that given type does not exist).

If you get deprecated info:

> You are retrieving the service locator from within the class [...]

Keep in mind that Zend in future version will remove `getServiceLocator()` method, so using service locator in controller is not a recommended. You should inject your dependencies through factory class.